# show table border even without data

Tags: ssrs-2012

There are four tables in my report which sometimes two of them will have no data on them. So, I want to show border of each table even if there is no data on it. Please help how can I show borders of table even if there is no data in each table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue.  Would you mind adding some examples of what is happening and what you'd like to happen so I can get a better idea of what isn't working correctly?

Comment: I am trying to make a bill form to be paid by our customers. each customer needs to pay from one item to four items. I have created four tables which gets data from four datasets. Each table will have only one raw for only one item which gets data from parameter1 ,p2, p3 and p4. I have set 0 point space between each table which looks like one table with four rows on it.

Comment: Now if I make a bill for four items, there is no problem and it works great. But, if I make bill for only one item and select null for 3 other parameters, one full page report will decrease to half page which I don't like that.. Therefore I am thinking to have table borders for null values to fit the report on one page.

Comment: So basically, you're saying the `NULL` tables aren't showing up at all?  Could you maybe add some images to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I inserted three rectangles with the same size of table and placed them on the back of three rows. But still if I add value to only one parameter, the rectangle disappears with empty tables.If you can help me to have a fixed position for each report item, it will help me as well.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to see images of this report to be able to make legitimate suggestions.  One thing that could help is adding columns to your report.  Click the blue background outside of the report and you should see the report properties in the Properties window.  In the "Page" group, there's a property for "Columns" which allows you to set another column and spacing.

Comment: https://imgur.com/dpQTHHX  what it is at the moment  and what I want https://imgur.com/XBjUM2v   the screenshot of SSRS https://imgur.com/Pm7iFbB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your data source is a SQL Server?  If so, the best solution for this might be to modify the query that you're getting your data from to include rows when there is no data.  In my reports, I've done this often to generate the correct number of rows.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(rowNum INT, barcode INT, title VARCHAR(100), author VARCHAR(100), fine INT)
INSERT INTO #temp(rowNum, barcode, title, author, fine)
FROM YourTable

DECLARE @h INT
SET @h = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp)
WHILE @h < 4
BEGIN
   SET @h = @h + 1
   INSERT INTO #temp(rowNum) VALUES (@h)
END

SELECT * FROM #temp ORDER BY rowNum
```

This simple query should `SELECT` whatever data exists, set `@h` to the count of rows, and add new lines with a line number until you have 4 lines, numbered 1-4.

Others on SO will tell you looping like this is inefficient and they are probably correct. They would suggest a tally table, though my SQL skills are lacking somewhat and this method proves effective in my uses.